# Ruby Array of Hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have a group of records being returned by an Active Record query. I need to somehow iterate over these to build an array of hashes that sort of looks like:

```
[
  { '15/01/2013': 3 },
  { '24/051/2012': 1 },
  { '08/07/2015': 22 }
]
```

The records returned will be in the form of having 3 records for the first, 1 record for the second and 22 records for the 3rd. I basically need a way to transform that into a simple hash like above.

Here's an example of my DB output:

```
[
    {
        "item_id": 21728,
        "id": 31731,
        "notes": "sample",
        "date": "2014-09-12",
        "created_at": "2015-08-13T15:16:06.074Z",
        "updated_at": "2015-08-13T15:16:06.074Z"
    },
    {
        "item_id": 21728,
        "id": 31732,
        "notes": "sample",
        "date": "2014-09-12",
        "created_at": "2015-08-13T15:16:06.104Z",
        "updated_at": "2015-08-13T15:16:06.104Z"
    },
    {
        "item_id": 21728,
        "id": 31733,
        "notes": "sample",
        "date": "2014-09-13",
        "created_at": "2015-08-13T15:16:06.112Z",
        "updated_at": "2015-08-13T15:16:06.112Z"
    }
]
```

Comment: So, maybe you could show us a query and output?

Comment: @Зелёный Ok, Added my DB output. Thanks

Comment: it's the `json`. in the Ruby `json != hash`

Comment: And what problem do you have when you try to iterate the DB result?

Comment: Look at [each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) - it has been used in similar situations - you can pass an empty hash `{}` as initial value and in the loop - keep track of counts of records against the date in the hash

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your DB results are stored in an array called **results**.

```
results.group_by(&:date).map{|k,v| {k => v.count}}
```

This, first groups your DB results according to their dates and then counts how many objects correspond to each date.